# How to speed up this loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to analyze each sample with different types, like using the 'table' function for sample 1 to type-a, sample 1 to type-b ... , so I wrote 2 loops to do this. But when the number of samples and types increase, it is really time-consuming. So if there are any methods to increase the speed? Thank you~
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbxIM.png)

For example,like below,

```
for (i in seq_len(nlevels(types))){
  for(z in seq_len(ncol(data))){
    ......
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Have you tried using dataframe operations? In my experience, it's usually faster than for-loops.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.